# Rejoining sentences from list into new text file format

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have two lists created from a two separate files and I would like to recreate them into a new format. I have the code below but I'm stuck in the writing to document portion:

```py
newJson = open("/users/skylake/desktop/newJson.txt", "w")
with open("/users/skylake/desktop/newNodeData.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content =[x.strip() for x in content]

with open("/users/skylake/desktop/newNodeData2.txt", "r") as d:
    dcontent = d.readlines()
dcontent =[x.strip() for x in dcontent]

#JSON format
"""{"id": , "label":}"""
for i in range(len(dcontent)):
    jsonData = '{"id":', content[i] + ',', '"label":', dcontent[i]+'}'
    newJson.write(jsonData)
```

Right now I'm getting an error stating that the argument in `.write` must be a string not a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you create the variable `jsonData` you are splitting up your stings with commas making `jsonData` a tuple.

Try this:

```
#JSON format
"""{"id": , "label":}"""
for i in range(len(dcontent)):
    jsonData = '{"id":', content[i] + ',', '"label":', dcontent[i]+'}'
    newJson.write("".join(jsonData))
```

Or this;

```
#JSON format
"""{"id": , "label":}"""
for i in range(len(dcontent)):
    jsonData = '{"id":'+ content[i] + ','+ '"label":'+ dcontent[i]+'}'
    newJson.write(jsonData)
```

Comment: Yes it worked! I have to learn how to use JSON formatting correctly, but this will do for now.

Comment: Any idea why the code stops writing 10 times before the end of the range? My list has 265 items and when the script finishes writing I just have 244 created in the written jsonData text.

Comment: That's odd. I'd try to debug your script in spyder or jupyter notebook by replacing `write`  with `print`. That may shed some light on your problem.